# Bounded integral operator $k$

Tags: functional-analysis

The following is an exercise of Conway's *Functional Analysis*, Chapter 2, Section 1:

If $(X,\Omega,\mu)$ is a measure space and $k\in L^2(\mu\times\mu)$, show that $k$ defines a bounded integral operator. (Exercise 7)

Comment: operator between what spaces?

Comment: I donot know. it's an exercise of Conway's Functional Analysis and I'm wondering about it!!!

Comment: Perhaps he is referring to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_integral_operator

Answer (score 3):

If $e_i=e_i(x)$, $i\in I$, is an orthonormal basis of $L^2(\mu)$, then $e_{ij}=e_i(x)e_j(y)$, $i,j\in I$, is an orthonormal basis of $L^2(\mu\times\mu)$. Hence
$$
k(x,y)=\sum_{i,j}k_{ij}\,e_i(x)\,e_j(y), \quad\text{where $\,\,k_{ij}=\int_X k\,e_{ij}\,d(\mu\times\mu)$},
$$
and $j\in L^2(\mu\times\mu)$ implies that $\sum_{i,j\in I}|k_{ij}|^2=\|k\|^2_{L^2(\mu\times\mu)}<\infty$.

If $f\in L^2(\mu)$, with $f(x)=\sum_{i\in I}f_i\,e_i(x)$, then $\|f\|^2=\sum_{i\in I}|f_i|^2$ and
\begin{align}
(Kf)(x)&=\int_X k(x,y)\,f(y)\,d\mu(y)= \int_X\sum_{i,j}k_{ij}\,e_i(x)\,e_j(y)\Big(\sum_{k\in I}f_k\,e_k(y)\Big)\,d\mu(y) \\
&=\sum_{i\in I}\Big(\sum_{j\in I}k_{ij}\,f_j\Big)\,e_i(x),
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\|Kf\|^2&=\sum_{i\in I}\Big|\sum_{j\in I}k_{ij}\,f_j\Big|^2\le 
\sum_{i\in I}\Big(\sum_{j\in I}|k_{ij}^2|\Big)\Big(\sum_{j\in I}|f_{j}|^2\Big)\\ &=
\Big(\sum_{i,j\in I}|k_{ij}|^2\Big)\Big(\sum_{j\in I}|f_j|^2\Big)=\|k\|^2_{L^2(\mu\times\mu)}\|f\|^2,
\end{align}
which shows that $K$ is bounded and its norm does not exceed $\|k\|_{L^2(\mu\times\mu)}$.

Comment: You could just use minkowski's inequality as well.